# Why is it that if I include a navigation property does it include some of the navigation properties of the property that I want to include?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have a problem and it is that when I load a navigation property of an entity, it loads the other navigation properties of the property that I am loading, which generates me as a loop.

- Company.cs

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string EmailPassword { get; set; }
    public int EmailType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;

    public User User { get; set; }
    public List<CompanySpecialty> CompanySpecialties { get; } = new List<CompanySpecialty>();
    public List<CompanySchedule> CompanySchedules { get; } = new List<CompanySchedule>();

}
```

- CompanySpecialty.cs

```
public class CompanySpecialty
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
    public int DurationInMinutes { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
}
```

I have these entities, the problem occurs when in the entity **Company** I try to load the property **CompanySpecialties** since the property company specialties loads the property **Company** that it owns, and it is property ** Company** reloads the property **CompanySpecialties** and so on.

What I want is to know how to load only once and not load recursively.

I wait an answer. Thanks.

Comment: JSON Serialization?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Hi, how would that be? Since I am reviewing the services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions in the Startup and it does not have a property that could help me which is called ReferenceLoopHandling. I use asp.net core 3.1

Comment: This has been asked many times in different ways. The answer is: EF performs *relationship fixup*. Use DTOs for serialization.